# Can't connect to server running apache over port 80

Tags: linux, apache-2.4

> Why does connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx via browser give me a connection timeout?

New instance, RHEL  7. Fresh apache installation. Version 2.4.6

`Port 80` is open and apache is listening

```
netstat -anp | grep 80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      5651/httpd
```

apache access logs are empty. Apace error logs are empty.

```
curl 127.0.0.1
```

Returns the page.

What else can cause  this? Where else should I look? Never had the issue with 2.2.x

EDIT: After updating `httpd.conf` to use IPV4:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10569/httpd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a networking issue, not an Apache issue. As you indicated, you can access the page using "curl" when run locally on the web server, but not from a browser on the desktop over the network.  Check routing and firewalls between the desktop and the server.

You could try using `nmap` from your desktop to confirm if port 80 is accessible over the network, but not responding:

```
nmap -sS -O -p80 ip.of.your.server/32
```

Comment: Yup. I missed that `curl` actually returns the page.

Comment: `iptables`. Apparently `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` is not the same as `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j accept`

Answer (score 4):

`tcp6` indicates ipv6 usage.

Either change the settings to use ipv4 by using:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

And not

```
Listen 80
```

Or try `curl localhost` or `curl ::1`.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the `httpd.conf` to use IPV4. Reloaded the service and the issue remains. Re added the iptables rule as well, same issue :/

Comment: Can you update your question with `netstat`?

Comment: This saved my day - thanks for this!!!

Comment: glad it helped 